# Swift generic type conforming to two protocols

Tags: generics, swift, ios8

I have a generic method in one of my classes where I want to have a generic type conforming to `UIViewController` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`. How can I do that? I thought of doing this:

```
func foo<T: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate> (#viewController: T) {}
```

But this code doesn't "recognize" the `UIPickerViewDelegate`. I also thought of using the pipe `|` instead of the comma but this is even worse, the compiler doesn't accept that.
Is it possible to do this or do I have to do 2 parameters for the class and the protocol? Or is there a nicer workaround?

Thanks for your help and Merry Christmas :]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your code:

```
func foo<T: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate> (#viewController: T) {}
```

declares **2** generics parameters:

- `T` which is `UIViewController`. And it's used as `viewController` parameter type.
- `UIPickerViewDelegate` which is `Any`. And it's not used.

Instead, you should use ["Where Clause"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_292), like:

```
func foo<T: UIViewController where T:UIPickerViewDelegate> (#viewController: T) {}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know the keyword `where` can be used there. But now I have another problem when calling this method in my viewController (conforming to UIPickerViewDelegate) by `.foo(viewController: self)` I get the following error: `Type 'UIViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDelegate'`. What's the problem? Thanks for any help again ;)

Comment: `class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {... }` works for me. How do you declare the viewController?

Comment: I have some other protocols, too: `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate`, `UIPickerViewDataSource`

Comment: @borchero Did you find a solution to this? I'm getting the same error, for some reason

Answer (score 18):

Since **Swift 4** you can use the power of **Protocol Composition**.
Here you go:

```
func foo<T: UIViewController & UIPickerViewDelegate> (viewController: T) {}
```

Answer (score 11):

Things have been changed in **Swift 4**:

`func foo<T: UIViewController> (viewController: T) where T:UIPickerViewDelegate {}`